# MODBUS, is there a maximum time a device can take to respond?

Tags: tcp, serial-port, communication, serial-communication, modbus

In talking to a MODBUS device, is there an upper bound on how long a device can take to respond before it's considered a timeout?  I'm trying to work out what to set my read timeout to.  Answers for both MODBUS RTU and TCP would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [*MODBUS over serial line specification and implementation guide V1.0*](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1.pdf) section *2.5.2.1 MODBUS Message ASCII Framing* There are suggestions that inter-character delays of up to 5 seconds are reasonable in slow WAN configurations.

*2.6 Error Checking Methods* indicates that the timeouts are configured without specifying any values.

The current [*Modicon Modbus Protocol Reference Guide PI–MBUS–300 Rev. J*](http://modbus.org/docs/PI_MBUS_300.pdf) also provides no quantitative suggestions for these settings.

Your application time-sensitivity, along with the constraints that your network enforces, will largely determine your choices.

If you identify the worst-case delays you can tolerate, take half that time to allow a single retransmission to fail, subtract reasonable transmission times for a message of maximal length, then you should have a good candidate for a timeout. This will allow you to recover from a single error, while not reporting errors unnecessarily often.

Of course, the real problem is, what to do when the error occurs. Is it likely to be a transient problem, or is it the result of a permanent fault that requires attention?

Alexandre Vinçon's comment about the ACKNOWLEDGEMENTs is also relevant. It may be your device does not implement this, and extended delays may be intended.

Answer (score 5):

The specification does not mention a particular value for the timeout, because it is not possible to normalize a timeout value for a wide range of MODBUS slaves.

However, it is a good assumption that you should receive a reply within a few hundreds of milliseconds.

I usually define my timeouts to 1 second with RTU and 500 ms with TCP.

Also, if the device takes a long time to reply, it is supposed to return an ACKNOWLEDGE message to prevent the expiration of the timeout.